# Telegram Bot Button Sending User phone number?

Tags: c#, button, bots, telegram

How To Add Button In my Bot -telegram bot- that button send me User Phone Number ,
and other Button send me Custom Command ?!

I need full example of creating the button and how to get data with C#  telegram.bot packge

example message:
[image: 1]

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/2-0-intro#locations-and-numbers